# Javascript/Jquery Refresh timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I have a simple system that refreshes a div every few seconds:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         $("#nownext").load("response.php");
       var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
          $("#nownext").load('response.php?randval='+ Math.random());
       }, 20000);
    });
```

Now, because of what the content is, it is more likely to update on the hour, or at half past. (Though not always). What I'd like to do it make the system refresh MORE often between a few minutes before and after the hour (and half past), just to make it more precise.

Is this possible/how would I do it without stressing out the client's computer too much?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the interval itself is going to be dynamic, you're going to have to use `setTimeout` instead.

Something like this (untested):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nownext").load('response.php?randval='+ Math.random());
    var minutes = new Date().getMinutes(), interval = 60*10*1000; // default 10 mins
    if (minutes <= 10 || (minutes > 30 && minutes < 35) || minutes > 50) {
        // update once-per-minute if within the first/last 10mins of the hour, or 5mins within the half hour
        interval = 60*1000;
    }
    setTimeout(arguments.callee, interval);
});
```

Comment: I agree with this, but his initial interval was 20 seconds and he requested _more_ frequent near half-hour breaks. The only thing I'd watch out for is "lapping yourself", so I'd add some sort of "in progress" state variable.

Answer (score 1):

Use setTimeout instead of setInterval so you can dynamically alter the timing of the next interval.  I'm not sure what the performance implications of creating and checking the Date() object ever millisec in the "Fast" period would be, but you could always tune that frequency up closer to every second if its an issue.

```
start_timer = function(timing) {
   var timer, d = new Date(), min = d.getMinutes(),
     timeout = 20000; /* slow timeout */
   if((min >= 28 && min <= 30) || min >= 58) {
     timeout = 100; /* fast timeout */
   }
   timer = setTimeout(start_timer, timeout);
   // Call your code here.
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    start_timer();
});
```