# How to refresh a view automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I have a Drupal 8 site with NodeJS.

I use the following module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/private_message_nodejs

For the installation, I followed the instructions in the documentation of the module page :

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/private-message

I created a page view and want it updated automatically.

I created a JS file in my sub theme :

```
(function ($) {
  'use strict';

  $('.view-inbox').trigger('RefreshView');

}(jQuery));
```

But it does not work.

How to refresh a view automatically ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LErSg.png)

Comment: Did you try  $('.view-inbox').triggerHandler('RefreshView');

Comment: @MouadKhali Thank you, I just tested but it does not work :-(

Comment: You will need to use a javascript timer to call whatever function does the restore. An example can be found at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992127/javascript-jquery-refresh-timer